# "Expected Class name" Error for Inheritance

Tags: c++, xcode, oop, inheritance, compiler-errors

### Problem

Currently designing a GUI game, and I've finished the basic OOP aspects of the game(along with 90% of all non-abstract classes). However, I tried extending a class called Protester to this class which caused the error at line 5 here:

```
#ifndef HardcoreProtester_h
#define HardcoreProtester_h
#include "Protester.h"

class HardcoreProtester : public Protester{
public:
    HardcoreProtester(StudentWorld* w, int x, int y) : Protester(w, x, y, IID_HARD_CORE_PROTESTER, 20){};
private:
};

#endif /* HardcoreProtester_h */
```

when extending from this

```
#ifndef Protester_h
#define Protester_h
#include "Actor.h"
#include "StudentWorld.h"

class Protester : public Human{
static const int INIT_PERP_TICK = 200;
static const int DAMAGE = 20;
static const int SHOUT_WAIT = 25;
static const int MIN_STEP = 8;
static const int MAX_STEP = 60;
static const int EXIT_X = 60;
static const int EXIT_Y = 60;
public:
    static const int INIT_HITPOINTS = 5;
    Protester(StudentWorld* w, int startX, int startY, int ID, int hp);
    virtual ~Protester();
    virtual void doSomething();
    Direction pickRandomDirection();
    virtual bool changeState(Direction dir);
    virtual bool isDead() const{
        return Human::isDead() && getX() == 60 && getY() == 60;
    }
    virtual bool isDeadState() const{
        return Human::isDead();
    }
    virtual void consume();
    virtual void setDead();
    virtual bool moveDelta(StudentWorld* world, Direction dir, int& xdir, int& ydir, int steps = 1);
    int determineRandomSteps();
    bool canTurn(Actor::Direction dir);
    Actor::Direction randTurn(Actor::Direction dir);
    Actor::Direction oppositeDir(Actor::Direction dir);
    Actor::Direction numToDir(int num);

private:
    int step;
    int restTick;
    int shoutTick;
    int perpTick;
};
#endif /* Protester_h */
```

I've looked on stack overflow for answers to why the error persists, and I've tried to break a nonexistent circular dependency (as you can see Protester does not even include HardcoreProtester). I tried to break any circular dependency by adding a

```
class Protester;
```

above the definition of HardcoreProtester.
However, this gives me the error:

```
Type 'Protester' is not a direct or virtual base of 'HardcoreProtester'
```

and

```
Base class has incomplete type
```

I also made sure the base class is not abstract(I was able to initialize it without any errors).

If this isn't enough information, here's the github for the project: 
https://github.com/OneRaynyDay/FrackMan

I apologize for any ambiguity in my question - I just simply have no idea where the error could be(hence an attempt for MCVE with github link). Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Also, using XCode to make this project. By this point into debugging I'm starting to suspect XCode of being the culprit.

In addition, just to be extra helpful and verifiable, here's a picture of the error diagnosis from XCode:
[image]

Comment: You need to post a [mcve]. What you posted is insufficient. Additionally, it seems very likely that you have garbled, hidden, or scrambled the real error messages and diagnostics. You claimed that your compiler error is "Type protester is not a direct or virtual base of HardcoreProtester". However, the class that you declared was "Protester", with a capital "P". Compilers are very picky. If there's a problem related to class "Protester", the compiler will not refer to a class "protester" in its error message. Without a [mcve], any attempt to figure this out will be a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That was just a typo, and it was the only typo. I changed it now, along with the title of the question to fit caps requirement. I'm using XCode so it's difficult to copy paste the error message since it pops up in bubbles and I cannot copy the text. Thanks for the heads up and I double checked that all errors are now correct. I also emphasized how I'm not sure what could be the issue with my program, and I've given as much info as I could without it being an entire essay(because tl;dr).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, XCode is not the culprit. It's not XCode's fault that you have circular header dependencies.

According to the compiler dump you posted, it appears that your `StudentWorld.h` header file has a #include of `HardProtester.h`.

This is a case of classical circular header dependencies.

First, you are including `Protester.h`.

Before `Protester.h` even gets to its definition of the `Protester` class, it has an `#include` of `StudentWorld.h`.

`StudentWorld.h` must have an #include of `HardProtester.h`, according to your compiler's error diagnostics.

Now, your `HardProtester.h` has it's own include of `Protester.h`. But, because its ifndef/define guard has already been set, in the first include of `Protester.h`, the second #include of this header file becomes empty text.

And now, upon returning to `HardProtester.h`, you attempt to declare it's class.

Now, if you have been paying attention carefully, you should've figured out that the `Protester` class has not yet been declared, yet this header file attempts to declare its subclass.

There's your problem. You need to completely refactor how your header files depend on each other, to eliminate this circular dependency. Merely sticking a "class Protester" in `HardProtester.h` is insufficient. The entire class must be defined, not just declared, before you can declare any subclasses.

Comment: I see... Thank you! I'm on my way to fixing that issue. However, why is it that when I had a circular dependency of only Protester.h with StudentWorld.h, it didn't cause an error?

Comment: Without seeing the complete contents of all header files, instead of the obviously abbreviated contents you posted, and how the classes they declare really depend on each other, it is not possible to provide an authoritative answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have a circular dependency between Protester.h and StudentWorld.h

Try fixing that and see if it helps.